# What is the correct accounting for purchases made on personal credit card?

Tags: accounting

I recently started an LLC. The LLC does not have a credit card of its own yet, and I've had to use my personal card to make purchases which I paid through personal funds. (Yes, I know I shouldn't do it that way)

What is the correct way to account for this in my business ledger? Would I debit an expense, somehow add equity from my personal payment as cash(?), and then credit the expense?

Comment: What if you add accounts which are like existing accounts but have "(paid with personal funds)" added to the name, then pay yourself?  For example, "Office Equipment" and "Office Equipment (paid with personal funds)".

Answer (score 1):

If you used your personal card, then the LLC owes you some money. To take this into account in your own personal accounting:

```
Debit: Accounts Receivable (LLC stuff paid with personal funds), XXX EUR
Credit: Credit Card, XXX EUR
```

And in your LLC accounting:

```
Debit: Office Equipment
Credit: Accounts Payable (paid with personal funds), XXX EUR
```

Don't use the existing account augmented with `(paid with personal funds)`. It's not proper way to do it, as the `(paid with personal funds)` is not a property of the equipment; it's a property of who you owe and how much.